# How to extract large .tar.gz file on FTP

Tags: backup, ftp, wordpress

So I have a .tar.gz wordpress backup file of size 1.6 GB. When I try to extract this file using FTP file manager, it partially extracts it.

Comment: Try Stuffit expander as another option

Comment: Instead of capitalizing the whole question you should open Terminal.app and enter `man tar`. Online: [Apple man tar](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html). Tool: [Keko](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/)

Comment: I don`t have access to the terminal.